# Introducir coordenadas(marcadores) en un mapa de google

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

DATA:

```
null([{"id":"0008","nombre":"FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS I","bbox":"-0.515358212377548,38.3869756882801,-0.514646718387274,38.3874205581019","count_geometrias":2098,"plantas":"{P1,P3,P2,PB,PS}"},{"id":"0206","nombre":"CENTRO INCUBADOR DE EMPRESAS","bbox":"-0.527918228743998,38.3810201755556,-0.526373500350929,38.3822401809516","count_geometrias":250,"plantas":"{PB}"},{"id":"0028","nombre":"RECTORADO Y SERVICIOS GENERALES","bbox":"-0.512869386775825,38.3843008776237,-0.51118534833184,38.3851009545756","count_geometrias":525,"plantas":"{PB,PS,P1}"},{"id":"0026","nombre":"FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS DE LA SALUD","bbox":"-0.51488946186396,38.3835841864622,-0.514392670169672,38.384200566229","count_geometrias":749,"plantas":"{PB,P1}"},{"id":"0040","nombre":"MUSEO DE LA UNIVERSIDAD DE ALICANTE","bbox":"-0.512495794840584,38.3804892561839,-0.511138071633159,38.3815679678406","count_geometrias":310,"plantas":"{P1,PB,PS}"}])
```

```
<script>
    var coordenadas;
    function testAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data', type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    coordenadas = item.bbox.split(',');
                    //console.log(coordenadas[1], coordenadas[0]);
                    initMap(coordenadas);
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<script>testAjax();</script>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>    

    function initMap(data) { //data es el nuevo coordenadas
        //console.log(data);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: { lat: 38.384628, lng: -0.513708 }
        });



        // AGREGAR MARCADORES DE LOS EDIFICIOS
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[1], data[0]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
            });

        </script>
```

Este es el código que tengo, en el que hay un data con distinta información, consigo obtener todas las latitudes y longitudes, pero lo que tengo que hacer es conseguir que todas esas coordenadas entren en el mapa como marcadores, no sólo la primera pareja de latitud y longitud, que es lo que me pasa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a tus preguntas anteriores te dejo una respuesta...
Tu problema es que esta llamando initMap en cada iteración y es incorrecto además de que `data` es la respuesta de ajax y no las coordenadas.

```
(function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data', type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: initMap
    });
})()

function initMap(data) {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: { lat: 38.384628, lng: -0.513708 }
    });

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var coordenadas = item.bbox.split(',');

        var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordenadas[1], coordenadas[0]),
            map: map
        });


        // OPCIONAL
        // Mostrar texto al hacer click en los marcadores

        // Ventana de información
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<span>' + item.nombre + '</span>'
        });   

        // Event listener, abre la ventana al hacer click en el
        // marcador
        google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marcador);
        });

    });
}
```

Te dejo el bin: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rozomavodu/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Por fiin muchas gracias! funciona perfectamente!